# SharePoint Graph API endsWith is not working

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Need to search file names in SharePoint using Graph API endsWith is not working, how to search file name contains or endswith using graph api?

**Success: Output response will list only files starts with 'Test':**
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drive/root:/directoryName1/directoryName2:/children?$filter=startsWith(name, 'Test')`

**Success: Output response received as 404 Not found**
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drive/root:/directoryName1/directoryName2:/children?$filter=endsWith(name, 'Test')`

**Output response:**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "Item not found",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-xxxxx",
            "request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "client-request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

**Wrong result: Item not found**
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drive/root:/directoryName1/directoryName2:/children?$filter=endsWith(name, 'Data.xlsx')`

**response:**

{
"error": {
"code": "itemNotFound",
"message": "Item not found",
"innerError": {
"date": "2023-xxxxx",
"request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"client-request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
}
}

**Output response will have all files in the directory**
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drive/root:/directoryName1/directoryName2:/children?search(q='Data')`

**Output response will have all files in the directory**
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drive/root:/directoryName1/directoryName2:/children`

**Directory view:**

```
TestData.xlsx
SampleWorkbook.xlsx
...
...
...
```

Comment: Having the same issue at the moment..

Comment: Is there any update in the issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `$filter` with `endsWith` is not supported for children endpoint. According to [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/transition-to-microsoft-graph-search-endpoint-for-onedrive-and-sharepoint/), `/search` endpoint will no longer receive any updates or enhancements.

The best alternative right now, seems to be [Microsoft Search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files).

I can include a few examples.

Search for files that contains term `Test` in the file name in specific SharePoint site and in specific subfolder of Shared Documents

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "filename:Test AND path:\"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/{site_name}/Shared documents/directoryName1/directoryName2\""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Search for files that start with `Test`

```
"queryString": "filename:Test* AND path:\"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/{site_name}/Shared documents/directoryName1/directoryName2\""
```

Search for `.xlsx` files that start with `Test`

```
"queryString": "filename:Test*.xlsx AND path:\"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/{site_name}/Shared documents/directoryName1/directoryName2\""
```

Search for file with the exact name `Data.xlsx`

```
"queryString": "filename=Data.xlsx AND path:\"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/{site_name}/Shared documents/directoryName1/directoryName2\""
```